# Почему метод sendVideo иногда отправляет видеофайл в канал телеграмм как прикрепленный файл (для просмотра), а иногда - как вложение (для скачивания)?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Вот код отправки видео:

```
function message_to_telegram($video, $text)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TELEGRAM_TOKEN . '/sendVideo',
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'chat_id' => TELEGRAM_CHATID,
                'video' => $video,
                'supports_streaming' => true,
                'caption' => $text,
                'disable_notification' => true,
            ),
        )
    );
    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), 1);
}
```

Перед тем, как отправить видео, оно рандомно выбирается из базы, а затем по ссылке, типа https://site.com/videos/223123123.mp4 попадает в параметр **$video**.

Когда выполняется данная функция, в телеграм попадает то прикрепленное видео для просмотра, то прикрепленный документ для скачивания. Отчего зависит такая проблема? От файла? Все файлы в формате mp4 без исключений. Я понимаю, что из-за того, что видео каждый раз разные, поэтому и результат разный. Но параметры для всех одинаковые: ссылка, **supports_streaming**. Единственное что, я не знаю, влияет ли как-то **caption** на то, каким образом прикрепится видео..

Comment: Возможно само видеофайл не соответствует требованям Telegram по виду используемых кодеков и разрешению экрана и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

тоже вот писал бота, для инсты и тик-ток и заметил, что есть ограничения на видео и на сколько я понял это объём в 50 мб

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос